# How to recursively check for a file's existence according to its extension and convert it with ffmpeg if it exist, using .bat file

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

i need to find files has .mxf extension in Drive D: and put a logo on it and convert it to .mp4 and search for for one with same extension and put logo and convert it to .mp4.
how can i make a .bat file for this.
thanks

i did it. thanks.
here is the code.

@echo off

```
for /R "C:\" %%f in (*.mxf) do (
echo %%~f
ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~f" -i E:\Logo\logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=60:50"  "%%~f.mp4"

)
```

pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /R "C:\" %%f in (*.mxf) do (
    echo %%~f
    ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~f" -i E:\Logo\logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=60:50"  "%%~f.mp4"
)
```